# Trying to get all accordions to open at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

So currently I'm trying to get all of my accordions to open and close if I hit the ctrl key. If I hit ctrl key I want all of the accordions to open including the nested ones as well and if I hit ctrl again I want them all to close.

Here's my code that I've been using if I only have to change my java script that would be the best but if I have to change other parts of it I'd be fine with that.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          setTimeout(function(){panel.style.maxHeight = null;}, 50)
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          setTimeout(function(){panel.style.maxHeight = "unset";}, 200)
        } 
      });
    }
```

```css
body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
                background-color: MintCream;
                border: thick solid;
                border-radius: 20px;
                border-width: thick;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .center {
                text-align: center;
            }
            table {
                margin-right: 50px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                text-align: left;
                
            } 
            th {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            td {
                border-bottom-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            table.a {
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
            .accordion {
              background-color: MintCream;
              color: #444;
              cursor: pointer;
              padding: 18px;
              width: 100%;
              border: solid;
              text-align: center;
              outline: none;
              font-size: 15px;
              transition: 0.4s;
            }

            .active, .accordion:hover {
              background-color: #ccc;
            }

            .accordion:after {
              content: '\002B';
              color: #777;
              font-weight: bold;
              float: right;
              margin-left: 5px;
            }

            .active:after {
              content: "\2212";
            }

            .panel {
              padding: 0 18px;
              background-color: MintCream;
              max-height: 0;
              overflow: auto;
              transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
            }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <title>Test Fixture Report, Controller CCA</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class = "center" style = "margin-top: 10px"> Test Fixture Report, Controller CCA</h1>
        <table class = "a" style = "width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Part Number:</p></th>
                <th>23-0522-50</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Serial Number:</p></th>
                <th><p style = "border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: 1px">?</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Version:</p></th>
                <th><p style = "border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: 1px">?</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Test Results:</P></th>
                <th><p style = "border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">?</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Data/Time of Test:</p></th>
                <th><p style = "border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">?</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Operator:</p></th>
                <th><p style = "border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">?</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><p style = "margin-left: 10px">Job Number:</p></th>
                <th><p style = "border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">?    </p></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    <button class="accordion" style="background-color:?">Self Test</button>
        <div class="panel">
          ?
        </div>
    
        <button class="accordion"style="background-color:?">CCA Test</button>
        
            <div class="panel", >
                ?
            </div>      
        </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to clean up my answer, I got rid of the code that wasn't part of the question.

I took your base code and turned it into a function. That you can pass the accordion element to. That way you only have to have a single function.

I also updated it to use querySelectorAll as that is more up to date.

After those general updates, I simply add an event listener on the body for keydown then look to check if the key pressed was the CTRL button.

```js
var acc = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");

const accordion = (el) => {
  el.classList.toggle("active");
  const panel = el.nextElementSibling;

  if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    setTimeout(function() {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    }, 50)
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    setTimeout(function() {
      panel.style.maxHeight = "unset";
    }, 200)
  }
};

acc.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", (e) => accordion(e.target))
});

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    acc.forEach((e) => accordion(e));
  }
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: MintCream;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: MintCream;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion" style="background-color:?">Self Test</button>
<div class="panel">
  ?
</div>

<button class="accordion" style="background-color:?">CCA Test</button>

<div class="panel">
  ?
</div>
```